# Reinitialize or check to see if menu is initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I am having an issue where I initialize the context menu on a grid, and it works but I have another function on the page that when clicked hides the grid, when I bring the grid back the menu no longer works, I am thinking that maybe re-initializing it will fix my problem.

How would I reinitialize the menu? If there is no "reinitialize" function than how can I check to see if the menu has been made before I destroy it and make another?

I know I can destroy it but I cant figure out how to tell if it is initialized first?

**JS:**

```
if(order.contextmenu("initialized"))
    order.contextmenu("destroy");
```

Comment: I was never able to figure this out so I decided to use a different context menu plugin with better support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fix this or figure it out, so I removed the context menu plugin and went with another plugin author who had good documentation (link below):

> http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/

Answer (score 0):

The menu can be (re)initialized - like any jQuery UI widget - by calling

```
$(selector).contextmenu({...})
```

but normally this should not be necessary:

If the grid was only hidden (but not removed), the menu should simply keep working as soon as the grid is made visible again.

If the grid is removed and re-created, then the selector should match some parent element that is *not* removed, for example like this:

```
$(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: ".grid-cell",
    ...
})
```

Then again the menu will keep working.

Comment: The grid (jqGrid) is hidden and then the data is reloaded, I have a field where you enter data and hit load, the grid loads up with rows and then you click back in the field to enter different data, onFocus the grid hides, when you click load the grid shows but with new data and the context menu no longer works, I tried both things you suggested before I posted for help and neither worked. Very odd for sure, however I changed plugins and it works great now.